# Applescript "random number" keyword breaks after importing foundation

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I have a random number generator in applescript that works fine until I import foundation for another section of code.

```
use framework "Foundation"

set myNumber to (random number from 0 to 65535) as integer
```

Answer (score 1):

because once you use "use framework", the script is gonna forget to use default applescript commands so to fix this, simply add:

```
use scripting additions
```

eg.

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set myNumber to (random number from 0 to 65535) as integer
```

this will tell the script that it can use the frameworks as long as it still uses default applescript commands

```
Hope this helped :D
```